# Why would my email address be wrong?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-for-teams

I wanted to sign-up for a free 14 days trial on Teams. <sup>Oh yeah !</sup>.

So I went on the [creation page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/create) and gave my email. Which was declined:

[image]

And I don't even understand why. Could we fix this please?

---

Edit:

If I start typing the 3 first letters, the auto-complete is shown:

[image]

Then if I press <kbd>Arrow down</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>, the `Submit` method is called with an incomplete address:

[image]

Which is why the error message is shown.

It occurs on both last FF & last Chrome

Comment: @Paulie_D is doesn't works with my real email address

Comment: @Paulie_D ok, the error message is shown but the email is sent anyway...

Comment: Which browser is this? I cannot repro with Firefox.

Comment: @Stijn added repro steps

Comment: OK, looks like a bug w.r.t. handling all necessary input events. It can be quite complex from experience.

Comment: @Stijn I can't agree more...

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Teams require a company email address, so gmail (and others like hotmail) are blacklisted. One reason to consider here is that access in most scenarios is gated by email domain. In this scenario - anyone with a gmail domain could join.

Comment: @ChanceHeath I didn't wanted to show my company address for privacy reason, but I can assure you that this bug occurs even with my real company address.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub not sure I understand the full situation. if you can send the specifics to teams [at] stackoverflow [dot] com I can investigate further!

Comment: @ThomasAyoub _I didn't wanted to show my company address for privacy reason,_ you should read this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129683/is-image-blurring-an-unsafe-method-to-obfuscate-information-in-images

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson nice post. But the blur applied is enough to avoid user seeing the post with clear email address and sending spam. If someone *really* want to get my professional email, 3 minutes of social engineering would be enough.