# Why can't we create a team using a Gmail address?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'd like to know why we can't [create a team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/create) using a Gmail address?

> Sorry we do not allow @gmail.com email addresses to be used for
>   creating a Team. Please use a different email address, such as your
>   work email address.

**Why can I not create an account using a Gmail address?**

There is a 14 day free trial period. I want to try Teams to make a suggestion to my management about the tool. Yes, I have a work email address, but to use it I need to get permission and have to explain more details. Too much work... So what I normally do is, I try a new system using my personal email address and then I recommend it to my management if it looks good.  I don't want to even suggest something which I have not used...

Comment: @yivi We can't use our work email address to joing any third part site / communicate other than client/coworkers without permission. Even all our sending mails must BCC to ceo_bcc@example.com. That is the rule in our company.

Comment: If anyone is missing @yivi irony: when the company has to send hundreds of mails to all their clients, potential clients, suppliers, etc. the individual behind the account would have to spend most of its working hours to read each individual email (I know people that "read" emails by just opening them, just to close it and say that they have "read" them). Another irony is that this "rule" is best enforced in the MTA rather than the MUA.

Comment: Where I live (and thankfully; work) it would be illegal to require a copy of all outgoing workmail be sent to the CEO. Either way, as the answer says allowing you to make a team with a gmail account would open that team up for everyone else with a gmail account.

Comment: @ivarni illegal ? So how to track  if CEO want to track what his team doing with clients?

Comment: Ask them? That's what I'd do.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson we originally put this in there because email domain was the *only* way to gate access to the team. And if you used gmail then, well, everyone with a gmail address could join. Now we have two mechanisms - per user invites and verified email domain. Therefore, it's likely we'll remove verifying email from creation entirely in the next couple of months.

Comment: @ChanceHeath please do. While the work domain makes the most sense for Enterprise subscriptions, I'm not sure its the best solution for the smaller pricing model. Not everyone has an organization email for their small team.

Comment: Big companies may have multiple teams within them and they may well have disparate teams where the members of TeamA don't want those from TeamB to access their SO Teams area, and vice versa.  Even more commonly, TeamA may not know or care about the existence of TeamB; they just want only members of TeamA to access their SO Team.  Going to some 'per user invitation' system makes a lot more sense for big company scenarios.

Comment: Per user invites is the only thing that makes sense... Email domain verification should have to be explicitly enabled.

Comment: @ChanceHeath is it possible for you to list all domains that are currently blocked, preferable as an edit in the answer of ArtOfCode (as it is higher voted, although Stijn's answer has a start of a list) so the search engine can pick it up?

Comment: @ChanceHeath been a couple of months, any progress? Some startups use `@gmail.com` for their work email. Would like to use teams plz :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Some startups use gmail address? Don't they have a budget to buy a domain which cost $10.... Even a few multiple dollars for Gsuite or alternative? What a shame.................

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson well yes, some early stage startups do (from personal experience). Thanks for being passive aggressive.......................

Answer (score 57, accepted):

*raises hand*

You can probably blame me for this one, actually...

A team I work with, Charcoal, were alpha testers for Teams. When we got alpha access, we set about trying to break it; in doing so, I added gmail.com to our allowed domains for sign up. I had expected it not to work, but it did and was kinda useful, so... I left it there.

I ended up being inundated by pings at work the next day from people asking me to deactivate their accounts on the Charcoal Team that they'd inadvertently signed up for by following links posted in bugs reports by our team members. SE ended up asking us to remove gmail.com from the allowed domains, and it was blacklisted shortly afterwards.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_throw_the_baby_out_with_the_bathwater

Comment: pepperridge farm remembers

Answer (score 33):

@ChanceHeath explained this [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/why-would-my-email-address-be-wrong#comment590992_368094) on a related question:

> Teams require a company email address, so gmail (and others like hotmail, yahoo.com etc) are blacklisted. One reason to consider here is that access in most scenarios is gated by email domain. In this scenario - anyone with a gmail domain could join.

However, it looks like this has changed based on @ChanceHealth's [new comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369766/why-cant-we-create-a-team-using-a-gmail-address?cb=1#comment601585_369766):

> Now we have two mechanisms - per user invites and verified email domain. Therefore, it's likely we'll remove verifying email from creation entirely in the next couple of months

Comment: Does it mean that everybody with "*email@verybigcompany.com*" address would have to be on the same team?

Comment: @PM77-1 I believe it only means that everybody with that email address _may_ join any other team in the company. Probably still not ideal, but less weird. Also team admins can choose to allow registration either based on email domain, or based on individual invites.